# How to output a message when query result is [empty string] in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfloop, cfif

I have a query written in a stored procedure and the data is dumping just fine. Some of the results return `[empty string]` and in those cases, I'm trying to output a different message. Here's what I have thus far:

Looping through the query:

```
<cfloop query="#inactiveAdmins#">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left">#Admin_Name#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Dept_Name#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Acad_Lead#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Acad_Lead_Email#</td>
    <td class="text-right">#dateFormat(Last_Logon, 'mmm dd, yyyy')#</td>
  </tr>
</cfloop>
```

At the top of the page, I'm running this `cfif` statement.

```
<cfif #inactiveAdmins.Last_Logon# eq "">
  Never Logged On
<cfelse>
  #inactiveAdmins.Last_Logon#
</cfif>
```

But, in my output, I'm still getting a display with no message.

When I try to run the condition inside the loop, I get the following:

[image]

Comment: Did you try the condition inside the loop?

Comment: Is all of this in a `<cfoutput>` ?

Comment: @JamesAMohler - Yes. The entire page is wrapped in `<cfoutput>`.

Comment: @RRK - I've updated the OP with a response to your question.

Comment: Did you try putting it in the loop like this? `<td><cfif #inactiveAdmins.Last_Logon# eq "">Never Logged On<cfelse>#inactiveAdmins.Last_Logon#</cfif></td>`?

Comment: @RRK - with that output, I feel like I'm getting somewhere, but I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: The result you added does not look like it was added inside a table structure.

Comment: someone already added it as answer. I think you can mark that.

Comment: I hadn't refreshed it to see that answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this supposed to be inside your table? Make sure you wrap it inside a tr and td.

```
<cfloop query="#inactiveAdmins#">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left">#Admin_Name#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Dept_Name#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Acad_Lead#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Acad_Lead_Email#</td>
    <td class="text-right">#(Len(Last_Logon) ? dateFormat(Last_Logon, 'mmm dd, yyyy') : 'Never Logged On')#</td>
  </tr>
</cfloop>
```

Or the long form:

```
<cfloop query="#inactiveAdmins#">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-left">#Admin_Name#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Dept_Name#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Acad_Lead#</td>
    <td class="text-left">#Acad_Lead_Email#</td>
    <td class="text-right">
        <cfif Len(Last_Logon)>
            #dateFormat(Last_Logon, 'mmm dd, yyyy')#
        <cfelse>
            Never Logged On
        </cfif>
    </td>
  </tr>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: You used a ternary. That's awesome.

Comment: I might do `isDate(Last_Logon)` instead of `Len(Last_Logon)`